# In this Javascript exercism, do I need to explicitly export the function definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my Javascript solution to rna-transcription exercism exercise:

```
var nucleoMap = {
  'C': 'G',
  'G': 'C',
  'A': 'U',
  'T': 'A'
}

var invertConverter = function (obj) {
  var new_obj = {};

  for (var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      new_obj[obj[prop]] = prop;
    }
  }

  return new_obj;
};

var splitStrandToArray = function(strand) {
  return strand.split('')
}

module.exports = function() {
  this.toRna = function(strand) {
    var strandArray = splitStrandToArray(strand)
    var converted = ''

    strandArray.forEach(function(letter) {
      converted = converted + nucleoMap[letter]
    })

    return converted;
  }

  this.toDna = function(strand) {
    var strandArray = splitStrandToArray(strand);
    var converted = ''

    strandArray.forEach(function(letter) {
      converted = converted + invertConverter(nucleoMap)[letter]
    })

    return converted;
  }
}
```

I am only exporting an anonymous function. This anonymous function refers to function definitions that I created earlier. Do these defined functions not have to be exported even though the exported function uses these defined functions?

This is my test that uses the exported function.

Also, require and export aren't native to JS right? Is this exercise using some kind of node-like syntax?

```
var DnaTranscriber = require('./rna-transcription');
var dnaTranscriber = new DnaTranscriber();

describe('toRna()', function() {

  it('transcribes cytosine to guanine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('C')).toEqual('G');
  });

  it('transcribes guanine to cytosine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('G')).toEqual('C');
  });

  it('transcribes adenine to uracil', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('A')).toEqual('U');
  });

  it('transcribes thymine to adenine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('T')).toEqual('A');
  });

  it('transcribes all dna nucleotides to their rna complements', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toRna('ACGTGGTCTTAA'))
        .toEqual('UGCACCAGAAUU');
  });
});

describe('toDna()', function() {
  it('transcribes cytosine to guanine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toDna('C')).toEqual('G');
  });

  it('transcribes guanine to cytosine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toDna('G')).toEqual('C');
  });

  it('transcribes adenine to uracil', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toDna('U')).toEqual('A');
  });

  it('transcribes thymine to adenine', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toDna('A')).toEqual('T');
  });

  it('transcribes all dna nucleotides to their rna complements', function() {
    expect(dnaTranscriber.toDna('UGAACCCGACAUG'))
        .toEqual('ACTTGGGCTGTAC');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, does it work or not? You only need to export what you want to reference in other modules. *"Also, require and export aren't native to JS right? "* Node.js follows the CommonJS module specification.

Comment: You are right, this is nodejs. Also librairies offers `require` like function for browser javascript, the syntax is not the same because it needs to be encapsulated. `requirejs(["helper/util"], function(util) { ....`